# Search multiple solutions in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, solution

Is there a way to search a term in multiple solutions at the same time?
I know that Ctrl+Shift+F will search the entire current solution but I need a way to search the term in three solutions, all at once.
I am using Visual studio 2010

Comment: Are you able to load three solutions in Visual Studio?

Comment: No..How should I do that?@Steve

Comment: Me neither, so I suppose that you have your answer. You can't do that with Visual Studio. Use a different tool like a text editor or something that can search your folders for files and their content

Comment: It's maybe too much work but: you could create a new blank solution (New Project | Other Project Types | Visual Studio Solutions | Blank Solution) and then use Add Existing project to add all the projects from your three solutions into the new solution and then use Ctrl+Shift+F.  Note that in the Add Existing Project dialog you can change file type to Solution File (.sln) and select a solution file to be added which cuts down the effort.  At least you can in Visual Studio 2013, I'm afraid I don't have a Visual Studio 2010 test environment handy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot search in multiple solutions.

You could, however, do a directory search in the three solution's directories. Just add the directories to the "Look in" box in the "Find and Replace" tool window. 
Just note that this is not the same as searching in a solution, as it will search through all files within the specified directory, not just the ones that are included in the projects of a solution.